# how to extract specific parts from a dynamic input and then put them together?

Tags: python, regex

Having in input a command, i would like to extract using python in a separate way the command, the path involved, the args and the extra commands concatenated, so that i can work with every single piece if needed, and then build them back all together

so, for example:

```
dir /a c:\users\ | find "stuff"
```

```
cmd1 = "dir"
args1 = "/a"
path =  "c:\\users\\"
cmd2 = '| find "stuff"'
```

this would be an easy task if the commands would be always the same or with the same patterns, but how can I do it if they are always different and with a different syntax?

some more examples:

```
more c:\windows\win.ini | findstr "fonts"
certutil.exe -encode \dir\file & something
```

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: We are here to help and give you ideas, not to write code for you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Is this CMD syntax? If it is, I'm 90% sure it's not a regular language, so regex is the wrong tool for the job and you should use a parser instead. For example, a pipe can occur inside a string, right? (I don't use Windows myself.) Although, the commands you're showing here are pretty similar, so is it only a subset of CMD syntax you need to handle? Like, how do you know there's always going to be a path provided as an argument? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fun! Here is my attempt:

```
import re

examples = [
    'dir /a c:\\users\\ | find "stuff"',
    'more c:\\windows\\win.ini | findstr "fonts"',
    'certutil.exe -encode \\dir\\file & something',
    'command -option1 -option2 -option3',
    'command "path with spaces" -option',
    'command > output.txt',
    'command "path with \'nested\' quotes" [optional argument]',
    'echo "This is a test" | find /v "exclude"',
    'python script.py arg1 arg2 --option',
    'echo $HOME',
    'dir /s /b | findstr /r "\.txt$"',
    'command1 | command2 | command3',
    'command1 && command2 || command3',
    'command1 | command2 > output.txt 2>&1',
    'command arg1^&arg2 arg3',
    'echo ^<output^>',
    'command1 arg1 ^| command2 arg2',
    'command -option="value"',
    'command --long-option arg1 arg2',
    'command [optional argument] -option=value',
    'command arg1 ^& command2 arg2',
    'command "path with spaces" ^| find "search phrase"',
    'python -c "print(2 + 2)"',
    'curl -X POST -d @data.txt http://example.com/api',
    'grep -r "pattern" /path/to/search --exclude-dir=dir',
    'ls -l | awk \'{print $1, $2}\'',
    'command < input.txt',                        
    'command arg1 -f file.txt',                    
    'command "string with $special$ chars"',        
    'command --verbose --debug',                    
    'command arg1 ^> output.txt',                   
    'command [optional argument1] --flag --option=value [optional argument2]',  
]

import re

def process_command(command):
    command = re.split(r" \| | & |&&|\|\|", command)
    print(command)
    for com in command:
        com = com.split(" ")
        print(f"Command: {com[0]}")
        string_parts = []
        i = 1
        in_long_string = False
        quote_mark = None
        arg_number = 0
        option_number = 0
        while i < len(com):
            if in_long_string:
                if quote_mark == com[i][-1]:
                    string_parts.append(com[i])
                    print(f"String: {' '.join(string_parts)}")
                    string_parts = []
                    in_long_string = False
                else:
                    string_parts.append(com[i])
            elif re.match(r"^[a-zA-Z]:\\|^\\", com[i]): # if it starts with a letter then :// or starts with \, it's a path
                print(f"Path: {com[i]}")
            elif re.match(r"^/|-", com[i]):  # if it starts with / or -, it's an option
                option_number += 1
                print(f"Option {option_number}: {com[i]}")          
            elif re.match(r"^(\"|\').+(\"|\')$", com[i]): # if it's surrounded by quotes, it's a string
                print(f"String: {com[i]}")
            elif re.match(r"^(\"|\').*$", com[i]): # if it starts with a quote mark, it's the start of a long string
                string_parts.append(com[i])
                quote_mark = com[i][0]
                in_long_string = True
            elif re.match(r">$", com[i]): # if it ends in a >, it's an output thing
                print(f"Output: {com[i+1]}")
                i += 1
            elif re.match(r"<$", com[i]): # likewise with inputs
                print(f"Input: {com[i+1]}")
            else: # otherwise it's some other kind of argument
                arg_number += 1
                print(f"Argument {arg_number}: {com[i]}")
            i += 1


[process_command(command) for command in examples]
```

Comment with some more examples if it doesn't work for anything

Comment: you are the hero i needed! thank you very very much!
one last thing: you split everything *perfectly*, the only missing part is how to build back, in the end, all the splitted parts(:

Comment: I leave that as an exercise for the reader ;) @user22173844